# Can't pass prop to component in svelte with typescript

Tags: typescript, svelte

I have this BigButton component with a title prop

```js
<script lang="ts">
let title: string;
</script>
<h1 class="text-2xl mb-4 font-extrabold">{title}</h1>
```

then on my index.svelte , I tried to pass the prop in different ways none of them work:

`<BigButton title={'Join a Game'} />`
`<BigButton title='Join a Game' />`

the lint is giving me the following error:

```
Type '{ title: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'title' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
```

Answer (score 3):

Use should [`export`](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-1-export-creates-a-component-prop) it, like:

```
export let title: string;
```

> Svelte uses the `export` keyword to mark a variable declaration as a
> property or prop, which means it becomes accessible to consumers of
> the component